# Changing WordPress multisite from https to http

Tags: wordpress, http, load-balance

I am trying to move the WordPress multisite from https to http.

I added the following lines in the wp-config file.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mywebsite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mywebsite.com');
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define( 'WP_CACHE', false );
```

I even went to the database wp_option table and changed the siteurl & home to `http://mywebsite.com` (not sure if this is required or not)

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/(login|register)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The website does show up as http as this is done for only the main website but not the other multisite in that single WordPress install. I get error when I go to another site as it takes me to https link (the page isn't redirecting properly)
I am trying to achieve this -> "when any site is opened in that same WordPress install, it should be in HTTP before it is put on load balancer"

Following this I want to put the website behind F5 load balancer that will handle the HTTPS and the website will run under https.

Should I change all the links in the WordPress Database to http by running a find and replace?
This might avoid the issue for multiple redirects.

Based on the multisite, is there any other way to do this or is the direction that I took above is the correct pathway?

Comment: Removing SSL for a website isn't a good idea.  You generally want to migrate the other way.

Comment: In some cases, removing SSL may not even be possible.  Do any of these sites use HSTS or have a TLD that requires SSL with HSTS (like `.dev`)?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am not removing the SSL but just trying to change the WordPress website to HTTP and have it on F5 load balancer.